# Getting data from a qproxymodel

Tags: qt

I have a qtableview which i populate.I use a qproxyfiltermodel for filtering purpose.I want to know if there is a way i can retrieve the data that is being displayed after using a filter.i.e  can i get the data from a proxy model.I need to do this because i have to display a summary of the details that is shown by the table.So when the filter is used if there is a way to retrieve the data from the proxy model i can do it right away rather than having to go to the model and filtering my storage for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the content of any model (including proxy models) using the following methods of `QAbstractItemModel`: `rowCount`, `columnCount` and `data`.